# I need to update the controller (edit notes) and pass the new values ​to the ListTile

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

The essence of the program is that you can add records to it and they are displayed in the ListTile. When I click on the card that the ListTile is in, it takes me to an edit page where I can change the name or content of the note. And I need the updated controller to be displayed in the ListTile when I click the save button.

The page where the notes are located:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
 final String zag;
 final String vm;
final String main;
final String second;
  const Home({Key? key,required this.zag, required this.vm, required this.main, required this.second,}) : super(key: key);
  

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState(); 
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

late TextEditingController _controller;
  late TextEditingController _control;

   List<String> notes = [];  
   List<String> vmist = [];
     late SharedPreferences _prefs;

  @override
  void initState()  {
    super.initState();
     _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.main);
      _control = TextEditingController(text: widget.second);
     _loadPrefs();
  }

  void _loadPrefs() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      notes = (_prefs.getStringList('notes') ?? []);
      vmist = (_prefs.getStringList('vmist') ?? []);
      if (!notes.contains(widget.zag)) {
  notes.add(widget.zag);
}
if (!vmist.contains(widget.vm)) {
  vmist.add(widget.vm);
}
    });
   
    _savePrefs();
  }

  void _savePrefs() async {
    await _prefs.setStringList('notes', notes);
    await _prefs.setStringList('vmist', vmist);
  }

....
 Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 18, right: 18),
                              child:  GridView.builder(
                              itemCount: notes.length,
                              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              childAspectRatio: 0.75/0.90,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 1.2,
                            ), 
                            itemBuilder: ((BuildContext context,int index) {
                              
                                 return Card(
                              
                                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 167,146,249,),
                                elevation: 0,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,                                  
                                  children: [
                                       
                                       Padding(
                                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                         child: ListTile(
                                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, right: 11),
                                          onTap: (){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => NoteReader(zag: notes[index],vm: vmist[index])));
                                          },
                                          onLongPress: () {
                                             
                                             showDialog(context: context, 
                                             builder: (BuildContext context){
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                                                ),
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 25, right: 25),
                                                title: const Text('Видалити', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
                                                content: const Text('Ви точно впевнені що хочете видалити цей запис?', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                actions: [
                                                  TextButton(onPressed: (){
                                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                  }, child: const Text('Hi')),

                                                   TextButton(onPressed: (){
                                                    setState(() {
                                              notes.removeAt(index);
                                              vmist.removeAt(index);
                                              _savePrefs();
                                            });
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(" Ваш запис було видалено")));
                                                   }
                                                   , child: Text('Так'))
                                                ],
                                              );
                                             }
                                             
                                             );
                                            
                                          },
                                          
                                            title: Text(

                                             notes[index],
                                              
                                              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 17.4,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600

                                            ))),
                                            subtitle: Text(

                                              vmist[index],
                                              
                                              
                                              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 12.2,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                                            ))),
                                          
                                          ),
                                       ),
                                      
                                     const SizedBox(height: 20)
                                  ]
                                  ),
                                 );
                            } 
                            ) 
                            )
```

Note editing page:

```
class NoteReader extends StatefulWidget {

  final String zag;
 final String vm;
 
  const NoteReader({super.key, required this.zag, required this.vm,});

  @override
  State<NoteReader> createState() => _NoteReaderState();
}

class _NoteReaderState extends State<NoteReader> {

  late TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  late TextEditingController _control = TextEditingController();
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.zag);
      _control = TextEditingController(text: widget.vm);  
  
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _control.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

void _update(){
  setState(() {
     String main = _controller.text;
     String second = _control.text;
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return new Home(zag: '', vm: '', main: main, second: second);
      },));
  });
}









// ignore: unused_element

   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new)),
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      _update();
                    }, 
                    icon: Icon(Icons.save))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 15,right: 15),
                child: EditableText(
                
                  maxLines: null,
                  backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black,
                   cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  focusNode: FocusNode(),

                  controller: _controller,
                  
                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 29,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, wordSpacing: -1, color: Colors.black)),
                ),
              ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15, right: 15),
                      child: EditableText(
                      
                        maxLines: null,
                         backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black,
                         cursorColor: Colors.black,
                        controller: _control,
                        focusNode: FocusNode(),
                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),)
                      ),
                    )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```